# trying to think of a way to query an email address that may or maynot have a dot

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql DB table that has a number of user supplied email addresses.

```
eg: fname.lname@gmail.com
```

When i get an email from gmail  I am trying to find that email in my DB .
The problem is that gmail strips out the . from the email address, so the "FROM:" email i am trying to look up in my DB is fnamelname@gmail.com

I can think of a way to do this, but thought i would see if anyone had an elegant solution
thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are getting emails from users that may or may not have dots in them and these are in a MySQL table. You also have a database of email addresses that don't have dots in them (or maybe they do?) and you want to match the user-supplied email addresses to the ones in your database?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to replace all instances of `.` on both sides of the query: `WHERE REPLACE(useremail, '.', '') = REPLACE(myemail, '.', '')` since it doesn't matter whether you compare `@gmailcom` or `@gmail.com`.